# Is there a way to make OnClickPendingIntent of remoteviews works in versions of Android earlier than 4.0?

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, remoteview

I have the following problem.

The notifications of my application don't work well in versions of Android earlier than 4.0 because the OnClickPendingIntent doesn't works.

How I can do?